# Too big separations between sections

Tags: formatting

My code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\iffalse
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Arial}
\fi
\title{
    \vbox spread 0.5cm{The Title}
    \vbox spread 0.5cm{{\large Some Extra Information}}
    %{\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{logo}}
    }
\author{Name Surname}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\flushleft
\abstract
Some text here
\chapter*{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Blank spaces between the title page, the abstract and the introduction are enormous and I don't know what's the matter. Any way solve this problem?

Comment: why the `\vbox` ?? the abstract should be `\begin{abstract> text\end{abstract}` do you really want the whole document flush left?

Comment: I used \vbox, because the separation between the second line of the title and the logo (that I currently commented) was too big
The document must be aligned to left -- this is requirement for my work
about the abstract -- thanks, I didn't know =)

Comment: OK if that's what you need (it's very odd though:-). but the form should be `\raggedright`. `\flushleft` is not intended to be used in that way it is the internal code for `\begin{flushleft} ..\end{flushleft}` environment.  `\vbox` though should never appear in a latex document (and ideally no markup at all should be in `\title`, any layout of the title should be in the specification of `\maketitle` that is the whole point of the separation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't clear which spaces you want to reduce, but after fixing the errors in teh abstract markup, they seem reasonable to me, the space after a chapter head is quite large but is intended for section level headings before the text. You could reduce that space, either directly or with the `titlesec` package. With an added section it looks like

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\iffalse
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Arial}
\fi
\title{The title\\[10pt]
Some Extra Information
    %{\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{logo}}
    }
\author{Name Surname}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\flushleft
\begin{abstract}
Some text here
\end{abstract}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\section*{Something}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: it still gives me a nice (around 1/4 of the page) spacing before the abstract, or maybe this should be like this?

Comment: OK, when I put some more text, then it goes up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\titleformat*` from the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.1\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
asdkfjhsakdjfhsdaf
\section{Second}
asldfhsajldfh
\end{document}
```